# Carthage update is failing with error 'could not posix spawn 35'

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

[image]

I have an application which was developed in Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2. Now I am trying to convert it to Swift 3.0.2, as the dependency manager I am using is Carthage. Now I am updating my Carthage so that all the frameworks should support swift 3.0.2. For this, first I have used the following command:

```
"carthage update --platform iOS"
```

It now fetches all the dependencies and check out all the dependencies but then after checkout it starts to build the dependencies and while building the dependency it just fails with an error.

Here is a attached screenshot of the error. I am totally blank on what I am missing in this case:

Comment: can you post your Cartfile?

Comment: Did you get the partial answer you were looking for? and do post the cart file.

Comment: (Aside: Rani, I've been editing some of your posts, and my advice is that it would be really helpful if you could make more of an effort with your case, spelling and formatting, especially now you have been a member for seven years. In this case, the preview window would have very clearly indicated that you'd converted your paragraph text to code formatting. Also, readers in general tend to find txtspk rather lazy, because no-one believes that "please" is too much trouble to type. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I faced the problem , this is how I resolved it:

1. I deleted everything that was checked out and got all new fetches and builds
2. Ran `carthage update --no-build && carthage bootstrap`

This problem mainly occurs in Xcode 7.3 beta2 (7D129n) toolchain. Carthage version0.12 will build the cartfile successfully if you set `xcselect` to 7.2.1.

Version v0.11 didn't have this problem. The problem occurs during the build, maybe because all the versions of Carthage dependencies don't match too. I also read a few posts which asked me to supply with `sudo carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`.

And you're using a really old version of Xcode. I'll suggest you to upgrade.